# Boto3: Unable to list contents of AWS S3 through python

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-s3, boto3

I am trying to connect to AWS S3 and list the buckets from my local machine through python. I am using the following code

```
import boto3
from boto3 import Session
from boto.s3.connection import S3Connection
from boto.sts import STSConnection
import pandas

session = boto3.Session(profile_name='mfa_0729')
credentials=session.get_credentials()
dev_s3_client = session.client('s3')
dev_s3_resource = session.resource('s3')
bucketname = 'my-bucket-name'
startAfter = 'my-claim-name'
obj1=dev_s3_client.list_objects_v2(Bucket=bucketname, StartAfter=startAfter )
```

There is a session token that I have to use that I saved in the profile along with other credentials. When executing the last line, I get the error

> botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the ListObjectsV2 operation: Access Denied

Can anyone point out what am I doing wrong? I am new to AWS and boto3.

Comment: According the boto3 doc (https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#bucket), s3.Bucket has a capital B

Comment: `AccessDenied` error usually means that your AWS Profile doesn't have proper IAM Permissions to list the S3 Bucket / Objects. Have you checked the IAM policy of your profile to ensure it has all the necessary S3 permissions ?